# All tabs keeps rebuilding when changing from one to another

Tags: flutter

I have a problem this problem where I change between the four tabs and every time I click on one of them, all 4 widgets within CupertinoTabView are rebuild.

I tried changing the ternary to a switch but the result is the same. 
Also tried using automatickeepaliveclientmixin on all 4 pages (with super on build method and the wantKeepAlive getter), but it's no use.

The code for this part is as follows:

```dart
class _MainTabsState extends State<MainTabs> {

  _buildCartButton(index) {
    // Some code I do here
  }

  int index = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoTabScaffold(
      tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text(I18n.of(context).home, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0)),
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text(I18n.of(context).search, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0)),
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
          ),
          _buildCartButton(index),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text(I18n.of(context).user, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0)),
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
          ),
        ],
        activeColor: Colors.orange,
        currentIndex: index,
        onTap: (ind) {
          setState(() {
            index = ind;
          });
        },
      ),
      tabBuilder: (context, i) {
        return CupertinoTabView(builder: (context) {
          return (i == 0)
              ? HomePage()
              : (i == 1) ? SearchPage() : (i == 2) ? CartPage() : UserPage();
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I just print something at the start of each page's build method and I see 4 prints every time I change tabs.

Also I'm using Cupertino because I need to keep the bottom bar persistent across the pages (I use a navigator on HomePage that leads to another screen and I need the bottom bar showing there, for example).

Edit: here's the code of one of the pages. I do a print in every page and every time i click one of the tabs I see the print on my terminal.

```dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  _changeLanguage(CartModel model) {
    if (I18n.of(context).toString() == 'Instance of \'_I18n_en_US\'') {
      I18n.onLocaleChanged(Locale('pt', 'BR'));
      model.changeCurrency('BRL');
    }
    if (I18n.of(context).toString() == 'Instance of \'_I18n_pt_BR\'') {
      I18n.onLocaleChanged(Locale('en', 'US'));
      model.changeCurrency('USD');
    }
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);

    print('hi home');
    return Scaffold(
    ...
```

Comment: what problem you are facing because of the rebuild. In flutter it is expected that the build method can get called at any time.

Comment: Build methods should use fields of your state class to generate a UI without any side effects, and the framework will decide when to call the build method.

Comment: I have the same issue. Any solution or workaround is much appreciated, please.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. This problem was solved when I organized the pages to be displayed in the CupertinoTabView by giving them a list.

```
    class _MainTabsState extends State<MainTabs> {

    _buildCartButton(index) {
    // Some code I do here
    }

    int index = 0;
 
    final List<Widget> _pages = [
    HomePage(),
    SearchPage(),
    CartPage(),
    UserPage()];

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoTabScaffold(
      tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text(I18n.of(context).home, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0)),
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text(I18n.of(context).search, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0)),
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
          ),
          _buildCartButton(index),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text(I18n.of(context).user, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0)),
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
          ),
        ],
        activeColor: Colors.orange,
        currentIndex: index,
        onTap: (ind) {
          setState(() {
            index = ind;
          });
        },
      ),
      tabBuilder: (context, i) {
        return CupertinoTabView(builder: (context) {
          return _pages[i];
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` to each of the Tab's widgets. For example:

```
class _SearchPageState State extends State<SearchPage> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin{
```

This will make sure your pages aren't rebuilt every time the user changes tabs.

Comment: Uh, that's what I did? I wrote that in my question and that doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share the code of one of the classes like `SearchPage`?

Comment: did you figure it out..?

Comment: The author never replied to my question. He had the `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` in the home page, but that's not where it needs to be. Hence my question.